# Changing DNS Records on remote DNS

Tags: powershell, dns, record

I already got my powershell script which does what I need.
(Check which server line is active and change to the other line)

This works fine, but i need to run the script from another client with less rights
(eg user account with permissions on those specific DNS-Records)

Is there a possibility to run  the command (`Get-DnsServerRessourceRecord` / `Set-DnsServerRessourceRecord`) from a non DNS-Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the DNS RSAT feature to the server you are running the scripts from.  It will import the DNS cmdlets along with the DNS MMC snapin/GUI.  Please note that this still requires a 2012+ or Win8+ level OS.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change DNS resource record from a non DNS server unless you are doing powershell remoting or RDP to the DNS server(AFAIK).

but if you want the name resolution to change in a specific machine then you can modify the hosts file using powershell ,like this(run the script as admin):

```
 add-content -Value "`nhostname 10.0.0.1" "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

Note: `n is for creating new line in the hosts file

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [dnscmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069(v=ws.11).aspx) instead of the powershell command.

It allows you to update DNS records on a specified server: